# Python, Using multiple threading.Thread objects increases execution time of each thread

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have found that when using the threading.Thread class, if I have multiple threads running at the same time, the execution of each thread slows down. Here is a small sample program that demonstrates this.

If I run it with 1 thread each iteration takes about half a second on my computer. If I run it with 4 threads each iteration takes around 4 seconds.

Am I missing some key part of subclassing the threading.Thread object?

Thanks in advance

```
import sys
import os
import time
from threading import Thread

class LoaderThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoaderThread,self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            tic = time.time()
            x = 0
            for i in range(int(1e7)):
                x += 1
            print 'took %f sec' % (time.time()-tic)

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, n_threads):
        self.n_threads = n_threads

        # kick off threads
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(self.n_threads):
            self.threads.append(LoaderThread())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'With %d thread(s)' % int(sys.argv[1])
    test = Test(int(sys.argv[1]))
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython, only one line of python can be executed at a time because of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).

The GIL only matters for CPU-bound processes. IO-bound processes still get benefits from threading (as the GIL is released).  Since your program is "busy" looping in python code, you don't see any performance benefits from threading here.

Note that this is a CPython (implementation) detail, and not strictly speaking part of the language ***python*** itself. For example, Jython and IronPython have no GIL and can have truly concurrent threads.

Look at `multiprocessing` module rather than `threading` if you want better concurrency in CPython.

Comment: Thanks. Using the `multiprocessing.Process` class almost directly in place of `threading.Thread` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

That's because CPython doesn't actually do simultaneous threading; CPython only allows one thread of Python code to run at a time: i.e.

Thread 1 runs, no other thread runs...
Thread 2 runs, no other thread runs.

This behavior is because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) However, during IO the GIL is released, allowing IO-bound processes to run concurrently.

Comment: Clarification: Python threads are real threads, but the GIL means only one thread worth of Python code can be executing at once. The trick, of course, is to have the heavy working parts of a thread not be Python code at all. Dropping into C (or Cython) may allow the GIL to be released.

Comment: @kwatford How's this?